# Hamburger Icon toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hamburger icon to the top of my website but the toggle for that is not working. I have change-1 class that is toggled when the icon is clicked but that is not happening. The console is also not showing any error. Please tell what might be the problem in this code.

```js
function Main() {}
Main.prototype = {
  initPreloading: function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.body.classList = "loaded";
    });
    document.querySelector(".block.hero").addEventListener("click", this.particleRibbons());
  },
  particleRibbons: function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas__particles"),
      x = c.getContext("2d"),
      w = window.innerWidth,
      h = window.innerHeight,
      f = 180,
      q = [{}, {}],
      m = Math,
      r = 0,
      u = m.PI * 2,
      v = m.cos,
      z = m.random;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    x.globalAlpha = 0.7;

    function i() {
      w = window.innerWidth;
      h = window.innerHeight;
      x.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      q = [{
        x: 0,
        y: h * 1 + f
      }, {
        x: 0,
        y: h * 1 - f
      }]
      while (q[1].x < w + f) d(q[0], q[1])
    }

    function d(i, j) {
      x.beginPath()
      x.moveTo(i.x, i.y)
      x.lineTo(j.x, j.y)
      var k = j.x + (z() * 2 - 0.25) * f,
        n = y(j.y)
      x.lineTo(k, n)
      x.closePath()
      r -= u / -100
      x.fillStyle = '#' + (v(r) * 127 + 128 << 16 | v(r + u / 3) * 127 + 128 << 8 | v(r + u / 3 * 2) * 127 + 128).toString(16)
      x.fill()
      q[0] = q[1]
      q[1] = {
        x: k,
        y: n
      }
    }

    function y(p) {
      var t = p + (z() * 2 - 1.1) * f
      return (t > h || t < 0) ? y(p) : t
    }
    i();
    return i;
  },
  initMisc: function() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.particleRibbons);
  },
  navIcon: function() {
    $(".hamburger-icon").on("click", function() {
      $(".one").toggleClass("change-1");
    });
  },
  init: function() {
    Main.initPreloading(), Main.particleRibbons(), Main.initMisc(), Main.navIcon();
  }
};
var Main = new Main;
Main.init();


// burger animation

//$(".hamburger-icon").on("click", function(){
//    $(".one").toggleClass("change-1");
//})
```

```css
html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #212121;
}

body.loaded {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text-align-center {
  text-align: center
}

.vertical-align-helper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.vertical-align-helper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.vertical-align-helper>[class*=vertical-align-] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}

.vertical-align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.block {
  position: relative
}

.block.hero {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  overflow: hidden
}

.block.hero .block__content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.loaded .block.hero {
  position: relative
}

.loaded .block.hero .preloader {
  bottom: -200px
}

.loaded .block.hero .main-nav {
  bottom: 0
}

.block {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.block.hero {
  background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block.hero .name {
  font-family: 'Expletus Sans', cursive;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

.block.hero .name span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.block.hero .subtitle {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 18px;
  height: 57px;
  width: 66px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.hamburger-icon .burger {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffee;
  height: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hamburger-icon .burger:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.change-1 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .block.hero .name {
    font-size: 12vw;
  }
  .block.hero .subtitle {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="loading">
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="site-main fullpage">
      <section data-id="hero" class="block hero" style="margin-top:0;padding:0">
        <div class="hamburger-icon">
          <div class="burger one"></div>
          <div class="burger tikki"></div>
          <div class="burger two" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="hero__canvas" id="canvas__particles" data-bg-color="#232323"></canvas>
        <div class="block__content vertical-align-helper text-align-center">
          <div class="vertical-align-middle">
            <h1 class="name">Chirag <span>Bhansali</span></h1>
            <h3 class="subtitle">Front-End Web Developer</h3>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: div with class `block__content ` is over the menu.so the click is not getting on the menu icon.try position relative and adding z-index to menu

Comment: Try to make `position: relative;` to your hamburger and change `z-index` property

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]  it provides tips on creating a **minimal** example - your code has far too much code that may or may not be relevant to the issue.  The process of creating a minimal example will also, in many cases, provide you with the answer directly.

Comment: add position:relative and z-index to .hamburger-icon class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make `position: relative;` to your hamburger and change `z-index` property

```js
function Main() {}
Main.prototype = {
  initPreloading: function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.body.classList = "loaded";
    });
    document.querySelector(".block.hero").addEventListener("click", this.particleRibbons());
  },
  particleRibbons: function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas__particles"),
      x = c.getContext("2d"),
      w = window.innerWidth,
      h = window.innerHeight,
      f = 180,
      q = [{}, {}],
      m = Math,
      r = 0,
      u = m.PI * 2,
      v = m.cos,
      z = m.random;
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    x.globalAlpha = 0.7;

    function i() {
      w = window.innerWidth;
      h = window.innerHeight;
      x.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      q = [{
        x: 0,
        y: h * 1 + f
      }, {
        x: 0,
        y: h * 1 - f
      }]
      while (q[1].x < w + f) d(q[0], q[1])
    }

    function d(i, j) {
      x.beginPath()
      x.moveTo(i.x, i.y)
      x.lineTo(j.x, j.y)
      var k = j.x + (z() * 2 - 0.25) * f,
        n = y(j.y)
      x.lineTo(k, n)
      x.closePath()
      r -= u / -100
      x.fillStyle = '#' + (v(r) * 127 + 128 << 16 | v(r + u / 3) * 127 + 128 << 8 | v(r + u / 3 * 2) * 127 + 128).toString(16)
      x.fill()
      q[0] = q[1]
      q[1] = {
        x: k,
        y: n
      }
    }

    function y(p) {
      var t = p + (z() * 2 - 1.1) * f
      return (t > h || t < 0) ? y(p) : t
    }
    i();
    return i;
  },
  initMisc: function() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.particleRibbons);
  },
  navIcon: function() {
    $(".hamburger-icon").on("click", function() {
      $(".one").toggleClass("change-1");
    });
  },
  init: function() {
    Main.initPreloading(), Main.particleRibbons(), Main.initMisc(), Main.navIcon();
  }
};
var Main = new Main;
Main.init();


// burger animation

//$(".hamburger-icon").on("click", function(){
//    $(".one").toggleClass("change-1");
//})
```

```css
html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #212121;
}

body.loaded {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.text-align-center {
  text-align: center
}

.vertical-align-helper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.vertical-align-helper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.vertical-align-helper>[class*=vertical-align-] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}

.vertical-align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.block {
  position: relative
}

.block.hero {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  overflow: hidden
}

.block.hero .block__content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.loaded .block.hero {
  position: relative
}

.loaded .block.hero .preloader {
  bottom: -200px
}

.loaded .block.hero .main-nav {
  bottom: 0
}

.block {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.block.hero {
  background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}

.block.hero .name {
  font-family: 'Expletus Sans', cursive;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}

.block.hero .name span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.block.hero .subtitle {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 18px;
  height: 57px;
  width: 66px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hamburger-icon .burger {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffee;
  height: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hamburger-icon .burger:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.change-1 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .block.hero .name {
    font-size: 12vw;
  }
  .block.hero .subtitle {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="loading">
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="site-main fullpage">
      <section data-id="hero" class="block hero" style="margin-top:0;padding:0">
        <div class="hamburger-icon">
          <div class="burger one"></div>
          <div class="burger tikki"></div>
          <div class="burger two" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></div>
        </div>
        <canvas class="hero__canvas" id="canvas__particles" data-bg-color="#232323"></canvas>
        <div class="block__content vertical-align-helper text-align-center">
          <div class="vertical-align-middle">
            <h1 class="name">Chirag <span>Bhansali</span></h1>
            <h3 class="subtitle">Front-End Web Developer</h3>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```